# PHP - Multiple instances of script accessing same resources

Tags: php, arrays, multithreading

I have to analyze a lot of information.
To speed things up I'll be running multiple instances of same script at the same moment.

However there is a big chance scripts would analyze same piece of information(duplicate) which I do not like as it would slow down the process.

If running only 1 instance I solve this problem with array(I save what has been already analyzed).

So I have a question how could I somehow sync that array with other "threads" ?

MySQL is an option but I guess it would be overkill?
I read also about memory sharing but not sure if this is solution I am looking for.

So if anyone has some suggestions let me know.

Regards

Comment: What form is the data that your are analyzing in ... a database, flat files?

Comment: Are you running this script on the command line or through a web browser?

Comment: I am analyzing an website(got permission from the owner) running scripts through web browser

Comment: if you have a data container (perhaps an array) that houses the data in the exact same order every time ... you could use a GET parameter and use that as a trigger to describe the boundaries the script should anaylyze, ie scrubber.php?trigger=1, and then set your boundaries to be 100-199

Comment: hey scripts are working non-stop(keep loading) so there is no way to use GET requests.And array will have like 100k entries which is far too much for GET.

Comment: grab the website data once, cache it for n minutes, and work on that.

Comment: I would use MySQL just have a table where you store the page URL you have started to analyze, its not over kill its a simple solution that will take a few minutes to implement.

Comment: By overkill I meant it would kill server
Like we have 20 threads and each would do SQL queries all the time(to check if URL was analyzed if not store it there.

Comment: What about using a MySQL MEMORY table? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Comment: If you were to use an array, what data would you store in it and what would be it's key?

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial task using real multi-threading:

```
<?php
/* we want logs to be readable so we are creating a mutex for output */
define ("LOG", Mutex::create());
/* basically a thread safe printf */
function slog($message, $format = null) {
    $format = func_get_args();
    if ($format) {
        $message = array_shift($format);

        if ($message) {
            Mutex::lock(LOG);
            echo vsprintf(
                $message, $format);
            Mutex::unlock(LOG);
        }
    }
}

/* any pthreads descendant would do */
class S extends Stackable {
    public function run(){}
}

/* a thread that manipulates the shared data until it's all gone */
class T extends Thread {
    public function __construct($shared) {
        $this->shared = $shared;
    }
    public function run() {
        /* you could also use ::chunk if you wanted to bite off a bit more work */
        while (($next = $this->shared->shift())) {
            slog(
                "%lu working with item #%d\n", $this->getThreadId(), $next);
        }
    }
}

$shared = new S();
/* fill with dummy data */
while (@$o++ < 10000) {
    $shared[]=$o;
}

/* start some threads */
$threads = array();
while (@$thread++ < 5) {
    $threads[$thread] = new T($shared);
    $threads[$thread]->start();
}

/* join all threads */
foreach ($threads as $thread)
    $thread->join();

/* important; ::destroy what you ::create */
Mutex::destroy(LOG);
?>
```

The slog() function isn't necessarily required for your use case, but thought it useful to show an executable example with readable output.

The main gist of it is that multiple threads need only a reference to a common set of data to manipulate that data ...